# Load denied by X-Frame-Options: does not permit cross-origin framing

Tags: .htaccess, iframe, cross-domain, x-frame-options

I want to use this frame on other domain, but it provides an error as 
"Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://blogerpost.000webhostapp.com/embed/3M-lv856hh8 does not permit cross-origin framing."

And in chrome it says
Multiple 'X-Frame-Options' headers with conflicting values ('GOFORIT, SAMEORIGIN') encountered when loading 'https://blogerpost.000webhostapp.com/embed/3M-lv856hh8'. Falling back to 'DENY'.

Refused to display 'https://blogerpost.000webhostapp.com/embed/3M-lv856hh8' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'GOFORIT, SAMEORIGIN'.

Comment: this is not a question!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options)